# Как экранировать кавычки при вставке JSON в PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Встал вопрос в добавлении в БД объектов. При выполнении данного кода

```
    #создаю словарь из атрибутов(head) и значений(lines)
    b = dict(zip(head, lines[i].replace('"', "").split(",")))

    #создаю json объект
    jsonarray = json.dumps(b, ensure_ascii=False)
    # на выходе получается, например ({"id": "666", "name":"вапв'аы"пы"})

    #добавляю в базу json объект в виде сырой строки
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO events (data) VALUES (%r);""" % jsonarray)
```

получаю ошибку на кавычках в строке "вапв'аы"пы".
Как это правильно экранировать, чтобы в базу вставить и в дальнейшем можно было с помощью SELECT получить выборку и отправить в виде JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
import psycopg2

b = dict(zip(head, lines[i].replace('"', "").split(",")))
cursor.execute(
    """INSERT INTO events (data) VALUES (%s);""",
    [psycopg2.extras.Json(b)]
)
```

Подробнее смотрите в документации.

В PEP 249 описано как передавать параметры в строку SQL запроса.
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15

В документации psycopg2 есть примеры.
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Json в psycopg http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#json-adaptation

Comment: не подходит, тип поля data - jsonb, по этому я в него и добавляю json объект

Comment: А так `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO events (data) VALUES (%s::json[b]);""", jsonarray)` ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Пользователь/PycharmProjects/untitled7/parse.py", line 34, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO events (data) VALUES (%s::json[b]);""", jsonarray)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Посмотрите исправленный ответ. На версии Postgres 9.4 такое сохранение работает.